# tensorflow warning for each loop, Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I train the model in a loop where in each iter I initialized a new model and trained it .
Here is my code:

```
def run_benchmark(dataset, augmentor, logger):
    accs = []
    for ite in range(3): 

        logger.info("iter ==> {}".format(ite))

        df_train, df_test = LOADDATA_FUNCTIONS[dataset]()

        if augmentor is not None:
            # augmentation
            logger.info("augmentating...")
            df_train['content_aug'] = df_train['content'].map(lambda x: augmentor.augment(x))
            logger.info("augmentated...")
            
            df_train_aug = pd.DataFrame(zip(df_train['content_aug'].tolist()+df_train['content'].tolist(), df_train['label'].tolist()*2),
                                          columns=['content','label']).sample(frac=1)
        else:
            logger.info("do not augmentation...")
            df_train_aug = df_train

        (x_train, y_train),  (x_test, y_test), num_classes = get_keras_data(df_train_aug, df_test)

        model = get_model(num_classes)

        logger.info("train begin==>")
        history = model.fit(
            x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=12, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), verbose=2,
            callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', patience=3, mode='max')]
        )
        best_val_acc = max(history.history['val_acc'])
        logger.info("iter completed, tranin acc ==>{}".format(best_val_acc))
        accs.append(best_val_acc)
```

However, after each iter, there is a warning info:

> WARNING:tensorflow:9 out of the last 9 calls to <function
> recreate_function..restored_function_body at 0x7f151b4f4d08>
> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the
> excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function
> repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3)
> passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your
> @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has
> experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes
> that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to
> https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#python_or_tensor_args
> and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more
> details.

How can I avoid this warning info?